# Should I strike-through an old answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

Recently I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221337/positioning-an-image-inside-a-link) where the user posted an answer and then, upon clarification from OP, revised his answer and code. The user then kept the old code in the answer but put the `<strike>` html tag to strike-through the old code.

Is this a good practice or should old code be removed when replacing it with updated code?

[Edit History of Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26221465/revisions)

Comment: Is the old code relevant? (In your case I doubt it.) Love strikeout, though, as it [enables one to highlight dumb statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200961/whats-the-fastest-way-to-pack-32-0-1-values-into-the-bits-of-a-single-32-bit-va/26201254#26201254) without giving offense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the past, I used to ask people if they would ever do this in their own blog, but I stopped asking this because some people actually think things like this are clever or cute.

So I will offer this principle instead: ***Would you ever see this in a newspaper article?***

No, you wouldn't.  Ergo, it doesn't belong in an answer either.  Answers should be *the finished product,* not some collage of editing attempts.  If you want to see that, look at the edit history of the post.

Comment: Programmer analogy: Would you leave old code commented out in your production code base when you write new code?

Comment: I pretty much agree with this, except I have used it myself. I posted an answer, made a huge assumption in one of my sentences, and then striked it out once I realised it wasn't necessary. I left it there as I felt it added to the answer, the kind of "this was my train of thought, but no, so if you think the same, you're wrong". 

I kind of regret it, it doesn't format nicely, and it could do without being there. That said, why do we have the ability to use it all if *answers should be the finished product*?

Comment: @Joe: Markdown is a tool, not a mandate.  Like most tools, it gives you the ability to do certain things, but lets you decide whether to do good or bad things with it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You're right. It's like using a goto in C#. Needed a bit of a wake-up there.

Comment: By extension, do you ever see a newspaper article with every other word turned into a gray blob?  Some posters just can't seem to stay away from that darned backtick.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that would be a good analogy if not for the fact that apparently people do that, a lot. Actually, I just stumbled upon an example in a Java project today where a method doing import validation just contained 50 commented-out lines followed by a `return null`. I've seen worse in old C/C++ codebases though, e.g. functions of 3k lines that contain a huge nested if statement with multiple branches, and suddenly there's 500 lines commented out in the middle of it. Just like strike-through in answers, it makes the code a total mess.

Comment: @l4mpi don't people know they have source control for that? (The revision history in our case)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum well, to be fair, the C/C++ project actually predates CVS and I don't have any idea what they initially used (I believe it was RCS because I remember a project manager mentioning how cumbersome it was to deal with locked files back then). Still no excuse to not clean that up once the project was migrated to CVS and then SVN...